# Regular Expression for SafeString

Tags: java, regex, esapi

I am using an inbuilt esapi validator. It is defined as follows:

```
Validator.SafeString=^[.\\p{Alnum}\\p{Space}]{0,1024}$
```

I am not very familiar with regex and after some reading, I understand that this expression is matching alphanumerics and spaces.

I would like to extend this expression to include *,-()&+ and /. I tried doing the following but it doesnt seem to work

```
Validator.SafeString=^[.\\p{Alnum}\\p{Space}*,-()&+]{0,1024}$
```

Comment: If you used the second version of the regex I posted a comment to @Fede explaining why NOT to use that one as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separate entry in validation.properties, OWASP's intent for `SafeString` is to provide a guaranteed safe string for any application. By accepting characters that can be interpreted as code in Javascript, you no longer have a `SafeString` as intended by the API.  That could have disastrous consequences if other parts of your application are utilizing `SafeString` as originally intended.

Use @[Fede's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/710099/fede) first regex, but address it like this:

```
Validator.SomethingElse=^[.\\p{Alnum}\\p{Space}*,()&+-]{0,1024}$
```

And call it like this:

```
ESAPI.validator().isValidInput(CONTEXT, input, "SomethingElse", MAX_FIELD_LENGTH, true);
```

Note that the "true" mark corresponds to whether or not a string can be `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the hyphen at the end since if you don't do it the hyphen works as range instead of a single char:

```
Validator.SafeString=^[.\\p{Alnum}\\p{Space}*,()&+-]{0,1024}$
                                                  ^--- here
```

**Update:** following **[avgvstvs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557153/avgvstvs)** comments:

> From 1.7 to later, you would have to add the flag (?u) to the beginning of your regex in order for \w\s to work.

You could try also:

```
Validator.SafeString=(?u)^[.\\w\\s*,()&+-]{0,1024}$
```

Comment: Your second regex has a fatal flaw.  The metacharacters `\\w` and `\\s` are only defined over the ASCII set by default.  Prior to java 1.7, your only solution was what OWASP did which was `\\p{Alnum}\\p{Space}` because those were defined over the entire range of UTF-8 codepoints.  From 1.7 to later, you would have to add the flag `(?u)` to the beginning of your regex in order for `\\w\\s` to work.  For clarity and explicitness, I would suggest using the OWASP version of the regex.

Comment: @avgvstvs thanks for the useful comment. I'll update the answer with your comment

Comment: The `(?u)` flag needs to be before the `^` metacharacter in order to parse properly.  `(?u)^[.\\w\\s*,()&+-]{0,1024}$`